# How do I customize the html of each field in a view?

Tags: views, theming

I have a custom theme and I want to edit the HTML of a view. I am able to create template overrides but I get stuck, it seems like the editable part of a view does not go deep enough.

I have a view displaying all of a content type. The content type has the following fields a name, an image, a link, and a description. I want to edit all of these with custom elements, classes, ids, etc and change the order of them. However the deepest I can get into a view is the `$row` variable, which already has this content formatted.

I've ran a function called `views_get_current_view()`. When I run it's return through print_r I see the information I need deep inside of it, but when I try to grab that information Drupal runs out of memory, I do not want to allocate more memory and I don't think that's the best way to solve the problem.

Long story short - I'm trying to get the fields of each node in a view and customize their html, when I get that data from a view it seems to already be already coded.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a View that displays content and not fields, eg, the whole node as it looks on a page or teaser, you can create a template called `node--view--VIEWNAME.tpl.php` (or even `node--view--VIEWNAME--DISPLAYNAME.tpl.php`) and then modify that however you want. If this isn't what's going on, and you have a View with fields, then you can reorder them in the Views UI and can definitely theme them independently as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding views-view-fields.tpl.php](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/overriding-views-view-fields-tpl-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are create any content type and select any content type name ex : your created a "news" is content type and many field as a 'id','name' etc.

after you have add a one php file name as a 'node--news.tpl.php'

and clear caches

this file always call a news content data